# How backup/export graphics stored in Zebra printer memory?

Tags: zebra-printers

I have a Zebra printer and inside its memory there are some images (GRF files) that I want to export as backup, is it possibile to do it?
I discovered only how to upload to the printer new images, print images but I did not find any way to download it from the printer to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will want to use the HZ command. It will return the graphic in a way you can send it to another printer.

From the Zebra ZPL manual:

**^HZ**

Display Description Information

The ^HZ command is used for returning printer description information in XML format. The printer returns
information on format parameters, object directories, individual object data, and print status information.

Format: ^HZb

Format: ^HZO,d:o.x,l

Parameters Details

b = display description to return

Values:

a = display all information

f = display printer format setting information

l = display object directory listing information

o = display individual object data information

r = display printer status information

Default: if the value is missing or invalid, the command is ignored

Parameters Details

d = location of stored object

Values: R:, E:, B:, and A:

Default: R:

o = object name Values: 1 to 8, or 1 to 16 alphanumeric characters based on parameter l.

Default: if a name is not specified, UNKNOWN is used.

x = extension Supported extensions for objects (parameter o) include:

.FNT — font

.GRF — graphic

.PNG — compressed graphic

.ZPL — stored format

.DAT — encoding table

.ZOB — downloadable object

.STO — Alert data file

l = long filename support Values:

Y = Yes

If Y, the object data stores the filename as 16 characters. The data is
only compatible with firmware version V60.13.0.5, or later.

N = No

If N, the object data stores the filename as 8 characters. The data is
forward and backward compatible with all versions of firmware.

Default: N

Example: This example shows the object data information for the object SAMPLE.GRF located on R:.

```
^XA
^HZO,R:SAMPLE.GRF
^XZ
```